# How do I get NSSound to play a sound in a user-defined class?

Tags: objective-c, nssound

This question is from an Objective-C newbie, so please bear with me. I'm trying to make sounds in my classes and have been successful using NSBeep() but not NSSound. Here is an example. Notice that `NSBeep();` and `[[NSSound soundNamed:@"Frog"] play];` work fine in the "main.m" program, but only `NSBeep();` works in the SoundMaker class. Any help in learning how to get NSSound to work is much appreciated.

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import "SoundMaker.h"

int main() {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"This is the main program.");
    NSBeep(); // Works fine.
    sleep(1);
    [[NSSound soundNamed:@"Frog"] play]; // Works fine.
    sleep(1);
    [SoundMaker makeSound]; // Only NSBeep() works.

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

SoundMaker.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface SoundMaker : NSObject
+(void) makeSound;
@end
```

SoundMaker.m:

```
#import "SoundMaker.h"

@implementation SoundMaker
+(void) makeSound
{
    NSLog(@"This is SoundMaker.");
    NSBeep(); // Works fine.
    sleep(1);
    [[NSSound soundNamed:@"Frog"] play]; // Doesn't work.
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as noted, the solution is to add a `sleep(...);` statement following `NSSound`. Here is the change to SoundMaker.m that works:

```
#import "SoundMaker.h"

@implementation SoundMaker
+(void) makeSound
{
    NSLog(@"This is SoundMaker.");
    NSBeep(); // Works fine.
    sleep(1);
    [[NSSound soundNamed:@"Frog"] play]; // Works fine.
    sleep(1); // This added statement allows the preceding "play" message to work.
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, if you set a breakpoint, does it get hit?

I have started only recently myself, so the +(void) looks weird to me; the book I am using only teaches

```
- (return_variable)methodname
```

[Edit]

I just tested it, added

```
- (void)playFrog;
```

To my interface.

I then implemented the function

```
- (void)playFrog
{
[[NSSound soundName:@"Frog"] play];
}
```

I called it from somewhere else in my application like

[`self playFrog];`

That worked.

[Edit 2]

After reading your code again, I noticed you didn't alloc/init your SoundMaker...

Try

```
SoundMaker *mySoundMaker = [[SoundMaker alloc] init];
[mySoundMaker makeSound];
[mySoundMaker release];
```

Comment: OK, are you ready for a weird one? I'm enough of a newbie that I don't know how to use breakpoints yet. Instead, I added an NSLog statement following SoundMaker's NSSound statement and started to hear a sound. So instead I tried a `sleep(1);` statement, and lo and behold, I can now hear the "Frog" sound in all its glory! So all that is needed is to follow the NSSound statement with a `sleep(1);` statement to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for that input. As noted, the testing prompted by your suggestions resulted in finding the solution. Incidentally, if I understand things correctly, since the "makeSound" message refers a class method and not an instance method ("+(void)"), I don't believe it is necessary to alloc/init.

Comment: Ahh, ok, so the + is like a (C#) static method? Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers, while okay, make it look more complicated than it needs to be. All you need is this statement (in Objective-C) wherever you want the sound to be produced:

```
[[NSSound soundNamed:@"Hero"] play];
```

You can find and test the various sound names in the Sound window of System Preferences.